# Laravel: The payload is invalid

Tags: ajax, laravel

How to solve this error-

> The payload is invalid.
>   C:..\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter.php#191

I got it during sending ajax post request.

```
<input name="telephone" type="tel" value="" id="phone-number">
<button class="button" type="submit" id='sendSMS' onclick="clickFunction(event, this);">Send SMS</button>
```

Here is my JS Code-

```
(function() {
    $('#add-announcement').on('click', '#sendSMS', function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-XSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
            },
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: window.url,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data) {
                // alert(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { // What to do if we fail
                console.log(
                    'AJAX error: ' + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
            },
        });

        return false;
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue solved, the problem was in axaj query, the query was incorrect.